# How to put a animation on dropmenu using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

```css
/*.dropdownMenuLista {
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s, visibility 0s 4s;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s, visibility 0s 4s;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.5s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s, visibility 0s 4s;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.5s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s, visibility 0s 4s;
  transition: max-height 0.5s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s, visibility 0s 4s;
  max-height: 0;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.dropdownMenu {
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.6s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.6s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.6s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.6s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s;
  transition: max-height 0.6s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s;
  max-height: 290px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  padding: 0;
}*/

ul.ulDropMenu{
        float: left;
    }
    ul.ulDropMenu li{
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
    }
    ul.ulDropMenu li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 9px 14px;
    }
    ul.ulDropMenu li ul{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    ul.ulDropMenu li:hover ul{
        display: block;
    }
    ul.ulDropMenu li ul li{
        width: 120px;
    }
    ul.ulDropMenu li ul li a{
        padding: 6px 14px;
        color: #2A2A2A;
    }
```

```html
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <ul class="ulDropMenu">

      <li class="pr-5 dropdownMenu">

        <a class="nav-link" id="navbarDropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="transition: color .4s;" href="#">Drop Menu
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          
        </a>

          <ul class="dropdownMenuLista">                     

            <li aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a style="transition: color .4s;" href="#">items</a>
              <a style="transition: color .4s;" href="#">items</a>
              <a style="transition: color .4s;" href="#">items</a>
            </li>

          </ul>

      </li>

    </ul>
```

How to put an animation with `transition` on this drop menu? I have this code that should put an animation on drop menu, but it's not working.

When  i  add the  classes `dropdownMenuLista`  and `dropdownMenu` the dropmenu stop working.

I'm using bootstrap, but I don't want to use the JS drop menu from bootstrap. I need a `CSS` version of the drop menu for some purposes.....

Comment: when you are triggering the transition? there is not hover or js code used to change the properties

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sorry but i did not understand your question. I know that there's none JS, i'm not using JS, just `CSS` and `HTML`, the dropmenu is working fine, but not the `transition` `class`.

Comment: in order to have transition you need to change values, when you are doing this? how it's not working? how you expect it to work?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't know, i don't work much with `transition`. I want something like this one: https://codepen.io/joshmcrty/full/RVjGdP I already have the code, as you see on the snipped. But it's not working, what you think?

Comment: If you inspect the above code you will see that we have a `:hover` effect that change properties and transition is there to allow a smooth change ... so adding transition alone has no meanig it won't do nothing, you need to trigger some CSS changes using hover or something else.

Comment: I think it's good to start reading the documentation of transition : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions .. it's important to understand the basics before trying to use it then you will find the answer alone ... You will probably get an answer with a working code but it won't help you if you don't understand what is happening.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It's not the first time that i use `transition`, and i was using this code before on another project, i just don't know why it's not working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole thing could be cleaned up a lot, but doing this would not explain to you what is wrong, so I will change only what is necessary.

The core issue here is that you cannot animate from `max-height` of `display: none` to `display: block`, because there is no `max-height` for non-block items.

Thus we need to remove switching of `display` of `ul.ulDropMenu li:hover ul`(`. dropdownMenuLista`) element and show/hide some other way. Since it is hidden in .dropdownMenuLista class, by `max-height`, `opacity` and `visibility` props, we need to enable those on hover.

Additionally, your visibility animation was 4 secs but others were < 1sec. Thus the possibly visible animations would run through before the element actually became visible after 4 seconds.

All changes are marked with comments it the snippet.

```css
.dropdownMenuLista {
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: max-height 1s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s;
  -ms-transition: max-height 1s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s;
  -o-transition: max-height 1s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s;
  transition: max-height 1s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s;
  
  /* removed visibility animation */
  
  max-height: 0;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.dropdownMenu {
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.6s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.6s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.6s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.6s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s;
  transition: max-height 0.6s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s;
  max-height: 290px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.ulDropMenu{
        float: left;
    }
    ul.ulDropMenu li{
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
    }
    ul.ulDropMenu li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 9px 14px;
    }
    ul.ulDropMenu li ul{
       /* display: none; - cannot animate */
        
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    ul.ulDropMenu li:hover ul{
        /*  display: block; - cannot animate */
      
        
        /* show by enabling all props that
        hide this element in .dropdownMenuLista
        style */
        max-height: 290px;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;      
    }
    ul.ulDropMenu li ul li{
        width: 120px;
    }
    ul.ulDropMenu li ul li a{
        padding: 6px 14px;
        color: #2A2A2A;
    }
```

```html
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <ul class="ulDropMenu">

      <li class="pr-5 dropdownMenu">

        <a class="nav-link" id="navbarDropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="transition: color .4s;" href="#">Drop Menu
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          
        </a>

          <ul class="dropdownMenuLista">                     

            <li aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a style="transition: color .4s;" href="#">items</a>
              <a style="transition: color .4s;" href="#">items</a>
              <a style="transition: color .4s;" href="#">items</a>
            </li>

          </ul>

      </li>

    </ul>
```